# Looking for simple backup program

Tags: backup, copy, duplicate-files

I am looking for a simple backup program that copies just files to a second computer. I do not want cloud storage or timemachine capabilities.  Just want something that will check a folder for new files and then copy those folders to a network location. Something like Cobian backup for Windows computers.

Running ubuntu 20 on both machines. Network shares up and running so just need something to automatically move the new files to backup storage.

Comment: Have you looked at the default Backups app aka deja-dup?

Comment: Try the stock backup applications and existing tools before "just" trying to re-invent them.

Comment: same. I am looking for a simple GUI which works just like Seagate backup or HP backup utility. No increment, no restore capabilities. These things are great but I don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `rsync` is the tool you need.

`rsync` synchronizes two directory trees and copies only the missing or updated files. It can copy over network through SSH. I find rsync to be a lot faster than backup programs like deja-dup.

To synchronize two locally mounted directories:

```
rsync -a source_dir/ destination_dir
```

Note that the destination dir can be a mounted NFS or SMB share.

To push source_directory to remote destination using SSH:

```
rsync -a source_dir/ user_name@remote_host:destination_dir
```

`rsync` doesn't perform encryption like deja-dup, but it is a lot faster and less resource hungry.